# Renaming S3 files creates temp folders

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, hdfs

I am trying to rename the S3 files which basically

> copy to  target + delete source

But in my case I am able to copy target but not able to delete source properly .
All directory structure remains same without any file ..
also it creates temp files in the main directory .

**Do I have to explicitly delete it after renaming ?**

Here is my code which renames the files

I have subfolders insode the folder.

```
val file = fs.globStatus(new Path(outputFileURL + "/*/*"))
for (urlStatus <- file) {

val DataPartitionName = urlStatus.getPath.toString.split("=")(1).split("\\/")(0).toString            
val finalFileName = finalPrefix + DataPartitionName + "."  + intFileCounter + "." + fileVersion + currentTime + fileExtention
val dest = new Path(mainFileURL + "/" + finalFileName)

fs.rename(urlStatus.getPath, dest)

intFileCounter += 1

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [apache hadoop rename documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/filesystem/filesystem.html#boolean_renamePath_src_Path_d), it says

> > The core operation of rename()—moving one entry in the filesystem to another ..

So its just **moving** the files and **not renaming** . More detail on the link above.

So I guess you will have to **explicitly delete the folder name after renaming** is complete

**Instead of renaming the files only, you could rename the folder as well. That would not require you to explicitly delete the folder name**.

Comment: I need to rename each and every file inside it ...Renaming folder will help?

Comment: then you should explicitely delete the folder after renaming. renaming is just like moving files. You must have read the link I shared